# SimpleMFRC522 stop reading after some time

Tags: gpio, python, rfid

My code stack after some time (example 1 day) after reading MFRC522 in loop mode. At the beginning it works without problems, after some time is not working anymore. I can't figure out why. Can you help me?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import array as arr

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pinList = [5,24,0,2,3,4,27,25]
rfidList = [1081714680121,871849641659,504025229752,275844158012,648722309022,118668796333,737282492797]
id  = 0

while True:
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
    id, text = reader.read()
    print(id)
    if id:
        if id == 828191200458:
            for i in pinList:
                os.system("sudo gpio mode "+str(i)+" out")
            time.sleep(0.5)

            for i in pinList:
                os.system("sudo gpio mode "+str(i)+" in")
            time.sleep(0.5)

        for i in range(len(rfidList)):
            if id == rfidList[i]:
                os.system("sudo gpio mode "+str(pinList[i])+" out")
            time.sleep(3.5)
            os.system("sudo gpio mode "+str(pinList[i])+" in")
    GPIO.cleanup()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Thank You!

The link of MFRC522 is [HERE](https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/master/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py)

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? Does it crash? does it get stuck? Where?

Comment: The code works great for 1 day. Reads every card, really, but after 1 day or after 5 hours, i don't know exactly when, stops reading without error or anything else. It simply stops reading, if i reboot the raspberry get back to work again, i can't figure out why

Answer (score 1):

At a guess it is because the code runs out of memory.

The code `reader = SimpleMFRC522()` creates a new object every time around the loop.  I suspect the old copy is hanging around in memory and not being garbage collected.

That line should be before the `while` loop.

Also the call to `GPIO.cleanup()` is almost certainly wrong and should probably be removed.

Comment: If i put outside the `reader = SimpleMFRC522()`, after 30 minutes it stops reading. The GPIO.cleanup() is for refresh. It's wrong?

Comment: The whole structure seems suspect to me.  However to find out I would need to look at `SimpleMFRC522` which I'm not going to do (and you haven't provided a link to it anyway).

Comment: The SimpleMFRC522 is the classic SimpleMFRC522 [here] (https://github.com/pimylifeup/MFRC522-python/blob/master/mfrc522/SimpleMFRC522.py) but if you're not going to watch it, i can just thank you for the reply and the interest.

Comment: You should really add that information to your question.